# Regex: match last occurrence of multiple possible words where one word is trailing subset of another

Tags: regex

I'm not sure if I'm phrasing this question properly and/or being a bit dense. I have the following regex:

```
^.*(foobar|bar|abc|xyz)
```

...and I want to match the last occurrence of any one of the above words. The initial quantifier is greedy so that I'll get a hit on the last occurrence and not the first, but one of the words `foo` is a trailing subset of another `foobar`, so if I have the sentence `one abc two foobar three` then the group match is `bar`, which is not what I'm looking for. It should be `foobar`.

https://regex101.com/r/fEzBal/1

Comment: You can use word boundaries `\b` to force matching the entire word `^.*\b(foobar|bar|abc|xyz)\b`.

Comment: Looks good, if you stick that in an answer I'll accept it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use word boundaries `\b` before and after your group to force matching the entire word.

```
^.*\b(foobar|bar|abc|xyz)\b
```

From the documentation:

> \b matches, without consuming any characters, immediately between a character matched by \w and a character not matched by \w (in either order).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fEzBal/2)